# Given a secret key and a string how can I quickly make sure the string is not tampered?

Tags: php, cryptography

I have a key, which can be considered secret. I am passing around a string, I must presume the user is able to tamper it and I want to verify it is not tampered.

I could use something like `mcrypt_encrypt` store the result, `mcrypt_decrypt` when reading or I could use `$hash = hash('sha256', $key . $string);` and store `$hash . $string` and then verify the hash. The question is a) speed of this -- is there a benchmark comparing the decrypt speed of various crypto algorithm speeds vs a hash b) if I hash several string which all have the same prefix, will that weaken the hash?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~aprakash/eecs588/handouts/05-digitalsignatures.txt

Comment: Care to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, for hashing with a key `hash_hmac` is the function I needed to use.

Answer (score 0):

To the second part of your question: no it shouldn't weaken the hash. If a user wanted to tamper with the string they'd have to find another string that hashed to the same value. Hashes are designed such that even very similar strings will hash to different values.

To the first question, it depends on your machine and a bunch of other things, it should be pretty easy to swap in a couple different hash algorithms and run some benchmarks for your specific machine.

Comment: Yes, theoretically that's how hashes are designed but is there any study showing that same prefixing does not weaken the hash? I am mostly just curious there.